# change menu based on layout name

Tags: php, yii, widget

I'd like to be able to append my menu based on the given layout. For example something like the below?, where [Entries Background] becomes visable if the current layout is /entry

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
'items'=>array(
    array('label'=>'Entries', 'url'=>array('/entry'),'authItemName'=>'SuperUser','visible'=>Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('SuperUser')),
    array('label'=>'Entries Background', 'url'=>array('/entry/more'),'authItemName'=>'SuperUser','visible'=>$this->layout = '/entry'),
),)); ?>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
    'items'=>array(
        array('label'=>'Entries', 'url'=>array('/entry'),'authItemName'=>'SuperUser','visible'=>Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('SuperUser')),
        array('label'=>'Entries Background', 'url'=>array('/entry/more'),'authItemName'=>'SuperUser','visible'=>$this->layout == '//layouts/entry'),
),)); ?>
```

I changed your condition from this:

```
'visible'=>$this->layout = '/entry'
```

to this:

```
'visible'=>$this->layout == '//layouts/entry'
```